# Localhost no lee el sitio que ya esta instalado en xampp

Tags: wordpress, localhost

Buenos dias comunidad!

Tengo un problema hoy con mi xampp.

Ya hace varios dias estoy trabajando un ecommerce en wordpress haciendo una previa en localhost.

Hasta ayer todo normal, pero el día de hoy, empecé a tener problemas con las conexiones del xampp.
Hice todos los cambios que indican y recomiendan por las redes:

- Cambiar los puertos del Apache y del mysql
- Habilitar el xampp como administrador
- Asegurarme que en ninguno de los puertos no este corriendo otro programa.
- cambiar el archivo de data por el backup

Cuando logro resolver ese problema, intento entrar en la versión de mi ecommerce que estoy trabajando, el archivo va directamente para reinstalar el wordpress en ese sitio, al rehacer esa configuración,no continua en la conexión y me lanza un error 404.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es con el único sitio que tengo ese problema. Podrían orientarme por favor en cual sería la causa y por favor la solución?

Saludos

Comment: Por la última imagen, pareciera que dañaste algo y los parámetros de ese WP están mal. Termina buscando ese wp-login.php en la raíz del apache

Comment: parece que estas sobre escribiendo la base de datos, create una db de cero o conectalos desde el wp-config.php, tambien recomendaria ponerlo en una carpeta no en la raiz del localhost